# jQuery Mobile hidden navbar button

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am attempting to implement a nav bar on a jQuery mobile site.

```
      <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="a.html">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="b.html">Two</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
```

I am not allowed to post images, however I can provide a link

(http://pupillogroup.com/matthiaspupillo/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Screen-Shot-2012-06-21-at-9.35.00-AM.png)

The issue is that instead of two evenly spaced buttons my site display two 33% button and one empty button. The added  has a class "ui-block-c ui-grid-null"

I have not made any changes to the css, jquery,js or jquerymobile.js

This may be a complication but I am also using phonegap.js, but that does not appear to be an issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Screenshot or it didn't happen

Comment: Are you using the latest versions of each? This may help [tut](http://www.digitalnoiz.com/mobile-development/basic-cross-platform-mobile-app-with-jquery-mobile-and-phonegap/)

Comment: Using the latest version of jQM ( 1.1.0 ) and jQuery 1.7.1 in this example http://jsfiddle.net/xYFuu/ your code works fine

Comment: I have added a link to the screen shot that contains both some code as well as the nav bar. Thank you for your help and I hope I am not the only person this has happened to.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the question. When I typed my question I retyped to code and it solved to problem.
The code that generates the error

```
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="a.html">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="b.html">Two</a></li>
    <ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
```

The additional button was added because my closing `<ul>` was missing its slash `</ul>`. jQuery was auto-generating a closing tag and creating the blank `<li>` which was adding an empty button.